# Static linking of SDL2 2.0.18 with VS 2019, (memcpy already defined bug MT setting.)

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I tried to compile and link a very simple SDL2 example code.
It works for all the following configurations:

- Win32 release and debug for both MD and MT setting in runtime lib.
- x64 release and debug with runtime lib \MD

When I compile and link with x64, release and \MT I get this error:

**Error     LNK2005   memcpy already defined in SDL2.lib(SDL_stdlib.obj)    c:\SDL2\libcruntime.lib

(memcpy.obj)**

This is the same problem kind of.

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/3662

Below is my c++ compiler command line:
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64 Release" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64 Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MT /FC /Fa"x64 Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64 Release" /Fp"x64 Release\SDL2.pch" /diagnostics:column

Here are the linker command line:
/OUT:"C:\Users\jerry\source\repos\SDL2\x64 Release\SDL2.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\jerry\source\repos\SDL2\x64 Release\SDL2.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "SDL2main.lib" "zlib.lib" "libpng16.lib" "libwebp.lib" "jpeg.lib" "SDL2_image.lib" "SDL2.lib" "winmm.lib" "imm32.lib" "version.lib" "Setupapi.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\jerry\source\repos\SDL2\x64 Release\SDL2.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64 Release\SDL2.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64 Release\SDL2.iobj" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64 Release\SDL2.ilk" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"D:\SDL2Lib\x64" /TLBID:1

So how to make this work with VS 2019 and x64 and \MT setting? can pragma guards work in someway. What I learned is that the optimizer is doing memcpy and other things.

Comment: Where did you get your SDL2 static library? If you've built it yourself, what build configuration it have? Is `SDL_LIBC` enabled?

Comment: @keltar Yes I did build the SDL2 static library myself. This is the command line for the static library c++:
/ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Users\jerry\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.18\SDL2-2.0.18\VisualC\SDL\/../../include" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob1 /Fd"C:\Users\jerry\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.18\SDL2-2.0.18\VisualC\x64\Release\SDL2.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "DLL_EXPORT" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0700" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /MT /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Zl /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\SDL2.pch" /diagnostics:column

Comment: @keltar here is the command line from the librarian:
/OUT:"C:\Users\jerry\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.18\SDL2-2.0.18\VisualC\x64\Release\SDL2.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /NOLOGO

Comment: @keltar where can I set the SDL_LIBC enabled? is it defined in SDL_config_windows.h you mean?

Comment: `SDL_LIBC` is cmake flag. If you're not using cmake, add `HAVE_LIBC=1` definition. Any good reason to use static library, by the way?

Comment: @keltar The solution is the following after your tip about HAVE_LIBC=1.
I had this line in SDL_config.h 
#if defined(__WIN32__)
#include "SDL_config_windows.h"
#elif defined(__WINRT__)
....

I changed it to 
#if defined(__WIN32__)
#if defined(_WIN64)
#define HAVE_LIBC 1
#endif
#include "SDL_config_windows.h"
#elif defined(__WINRT__)
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to keltar advice about the SDL_LIBC flag

Solution is in the file SDL_config.h change the following starting from row 32

```
#if defined(__WIN32__)
#include "SDL_config_windows.h"
#elif defined(__WINRT__)
....
```

and change it to this

```
#if defined(__WIN32__)
#if defined(_WIN64)
#define HAVE_LIBC 1
#endif
#include "SDL_config_windows.h"
#elif defined(__WINRT__)
....
```